# Blog titles from WP blog on plain html site?

Tags: plugins, html, rss, json

My organization has a plain html, actually asp.net website.  We recently were required to create a wordpress blog.  We host both of these sites ourselves.  I have been asked if we could have a dynamic list of links to our most recent blog posts on the plain html site and need some advice on how to accomplish this.  I realize one option may be to utilize the JSON api but wanted to know if there are any other options such as plug ins, RSS etc.

Comment: I would recommend using WP REST API as its officially launched now with 4.7